# Converting voxels to physical units in 3D image with non-isomorphic resolution

Tags: 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to convert measurements from voxels to physical metrics (microns in my case). I have two images.

**Image #1**: 3D image with a resolution of 5 x 5 x 5 microns along X, Y and Z axes respectively.

**Image #2**: 3D image with a resolution of 0.5 x 0.5 x 5 microns along X, Y and Z axes respectively.

Let us say I am calculating the diameter of a sphere in the above 2 images and say it is 15 voxels. In **Image #1** it is straight forward - the diameter in microns is 15*5 = 75u. But how should I do the same calculation in the second image? The resolution is different in different axes.

**Update**:

I am using Python [skimage.measure.label](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) to find the connected components and for each connected component (sphere in my case), I'm using [skimage.measure.regionprops](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) **equivalent_diameter** attribute.

Comment: For case 2 sphere looks like oblate ellipsoid. But how are you calculating sphere diameter from 3D image?

Comment: I am using Python skimage.measure.regionprops and my spheres are connected components found using skimage.measure.label. I'll update this in the original question